# Is it possible to use ODataQueryOptions with DTO's?

Tags: c#-4.0, odata, dto

`ContentType`  --> EF model

`ContentTypes` --> DTO

In my OData controller:

```
   public Task<IQueryable<ContentTypes>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ContentTypes> options) 
   {
        var result = options.ApplyTo(_repository.Query().Get()
            .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
            .OrderBy(o => o.Description))
            .Cast<ContentTypes>();

        return result;
   }
```

I get an error 500 when trying to apply the `ODataQueryOptions`.  Since the class already inherits `ODataController` do I even need to do the`options.ApplyTo(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this was to ensure the return type is the the DTO's type, and that the `ODataQueryOptions` are applied to the EF entity.  I then use Automapper to map the result to the DTO.

I have updated the answer based on @Schandlich 's suggestions, however some issues persist:

```
    [Queryable]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<ContentType> options)
    {
        var userId = 102;   // mock

        try
        {
            var results = options.ApplyTo(_uow.Repository<ContentType>()
                .Query()
                .Get()
                .Include(u => u.User)
                .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                .OrderBy(o => o.Description)).Cast<ContentType>()
                .Select(x => new ContentTypeDTO()
                {
                    //projection goes here
                    ContentTypeId = x.ContentTypeId,
                    Description = x.Description,
                    UserDTO = new UserDTO 
                    { 
                        UserId = x.UserId,
                        UserName = x.User.UserName
                    }
                });

            return this.Ok(results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The reason for using `ODataQueryOptions` is that I want EF to handle the filtering down at the database call level.  Otherwise, I would get all records returned, then the `Queryable` would kick in to return, say the first page of results.

I removed the Automapper code, but curious as to why not use this?

As @Schandlich pointed out, however, this will not work for `$select` or `$expand`.

Comment: The reason that the EF filter is coming in after is because of the way you are handling projection. Look at the answer I posted above. I would also look at your repository and make sure that the there is not a ToList() in there or other forced execution method in there. Also, this will break when you use $select or $expand as result will not be of type ContentType.

Comment: @Schandlich -  Your suggestion partially works, and when I exclude the `options.ApplyTo()`, I don't get all the rest of the OData information back such as value for `$inlinecount=allpages`, thus no paging details. I don't want to return all records from the db, then filter on the client side.  What about a case where there are thousands of records?    You are correct that doing `$select` or `$expand` fail.  How would I get this working.  Also, why not use Automapper to do some of the work?

Comment: Here is a good article on why not to use Automapper. http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code. The reason that paging is not working is because at some point before it is getting applied, the query is already hitting the database. I don't know if it is AutoMapper that is causing the issue or if your repository is. I might be the Cast statement. I would work on getting it working out of the box rather than trying to force expand and select to work with your set up. http://beyondtheduck.com/revisting-projecting-and-the-odata-expand-query-option/

Comment: That is the solution that I wrote and use. Just instead of calling EF from the controller, I create my own interface instead of an IRepository. The datasource that implements that interface just does a clean projection from the EF to your version of "ContentType". Rolling my own repository makes it easier for Unity to handle my data context.

Comment: Thanks, I've got some reading for later this evening.  The controller method is working - getting data/paging, etc.  I tried removing the `options.ApplyTo()` and only using the DF db context, rather than `uow`/repository, but same issue - no paging details (I'm guessing additional `top`/etc. filtering would also fail).  I added this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688857/how-to-enable-expand-and-select-on-odataqueryoptions

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on @ElHaix's answer. I cannot recommend more strongly against using AutoMapper to map from a data source like this. This is also assuming that the query applied to the repository is being applied before the call the database.

```
[Queryable]
public virtual IHttpResult Get()
{
    var userId = 102;   // mock

    try
    {
        var results = _uow.Repository<ContentType>()
            .Query()
            .Get()
            .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
            .OrderBy(o => o.Description)
            .Select(x => new ContentTypeDTO() 
            {
                //projection goes here
            });

        return this.Ok(results);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Also, I would try doing a $select against ElHaix's answer.

Comment: With the `[Queryable]` attribute and removing the `options.ApplyTo()`, I get 31 rows from the server. As I want to apply the filtering on the server-side, With `options.ApplyTo()`, the sql query asking for 10 records is executed (rather than later filtering on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with AutoMapper Project() extension. $select, $filter, etc were all applied to database query.

```html
 [TestMethod]
        public void DataShaping_With_AutoMapper_And_OData_Select_Test()
        {
            OracleMonitor myMonitor = new OracleMonitor();
            myMonitor.IsActive = true;

            var dbcontext = new MyDbContext();
            
            var datasource = dbcontext.Datasouces;

            Assert.IsNotNull(datasource);

            SetupAutoMapper();

            var odataQuery = Extensions.CreateDummyODataQuery<DataSourceDTO>("$expand=Fields($select=Description)&$select=Name");

            var withShaping = datasource.Project().To<DataSourceDTO>();

            Assert.IsNotNull(withShaping);

            var withODataQuery = odataQuery.ApplyTo(withShaping);
            Assert.IsNotNull(withODataQuery);

            string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(withODataQuery);

            Assert.IsFalse(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strJson));
        }
```

Comment: At one point I used Automapper... not anymore.  I suggest you take a look at Why mapping DTOs to Entities using AutoMapper and EntityFramework is horrible: http://rogeralsing.com/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/